# How to show 4 names on 1 line instead of each name on new line in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have been using this code to fetch data from mysql database and displaying it in column format i.e

```
a 
b
c
```

What i want is to show 4 names per row i.e

```
a b c d

e f g....
```

Can anybody help me in this regard

Thankyou.

Here is my code

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [modulus operator `%`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $i++;
   if ($i % 4 == 0) {
      echo "<tr>";
   }
   echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
   if ($i % 4 == 0) {
      echo "</tr>";
   }
}
```

As a bonus, you've got syntax error in your code. Look at this line

```
echo "<table border='1'>;
```

which 
should be

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
```

Comment: you forgot to increment `$i` somewhere :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$cnt = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if($cnt%4==0) echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  $cnt++;
}
```

Comment: You've somehow forgotten to close `<tr>` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","abc123");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");

   ?>
   <table border='1'>
   <tr>
   <?php
    $count=1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    if($count%4==0)
    { ?>
    </tr><tr>
    <?php }
    <td><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
    $count++;    
    }
    ?>
    </tr>   
    </table>
    <?php    
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```